# What's happened to Shirley in Community Season 6

Tags: community

So I just started watching the new Yahoo! Screen showing of Community Season 6 episode 1 and Shirley (played by Yvette Nicole Brown) is missing.

The absence is explained as 'spun-off', has she left to do another show (in fact she appears in a short clip at the end in some fictional series called 'The Butcher and the Baker).

Will she be making a guest appearance later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Variety article Yvette Nicole Brown Leaves ‘Community’](http://variety.com/2014/tv/news/yvette-nicole-brown-leaves-community-1201317743/) cited personal reasons:

> Yvette said she is leaving the show for personal reasons: namely, to
>   take care of her ailing father.
>
> “My dad needs daily care and he needs me,” Brown told TV Guide. “The
>   idea of being away 16 hours a day for five months, I couldn’t do it.
>   It was a difficult decision for me to make, but I had to choose my
>   dad.”

Shortly after leaving *Community* she was promoted to series regular on CBS' *Odd Couple* reboot. According to [TV Line](http://tvline.com/2014/10/04/yvette-nicole-brown-the-odd-couple-series-regular-cbs/) Brown highlighted the differing show formats as the reason for her depature:

> As Brown explained earlier this week, the multi-cam Odd Couple —
>   versus the single-cam Community — is “a better fit for the life I have
>   now,” adding, “My dad needs daily care and he needs me. The idea of
>   being away 16 hours a day for five months, I couldn’t do it. It was a
>   difficult decision for me to make, but I had to choose my dad.”

Given the good terms on which she left *Community* the door is probably still open for her to make a guest appearance, but I couldn't find a source confirming that.

Comment: I did see that article shortly after watching the episode but was then surprised to see her feature in a small featurette at the end of the show especially as those articles are dated from September and October last year